# Computing homotopy colimit of a space with free $S^1$-action

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, equivariant-homotopy

Context. I am trying to understand the argument in B.4 of Thomas Nikolaus, Peter Scholze, *On topological cyclic homology*, arXiv:[1707.01799](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01799) (on p147).

---

I am still lost. But from Maxime's helpful comment and replies, let me  list out my concerns - which are listed as (X),(Y),(Z).

---

**The proof of B.4 spelt out in steps: (read the numericals for the main steps)**

1. We begin with a $1$ -category $\Lambda_\infty$ with a $B \Bbb Z $-action. We want to show
   $$|\Lambda_1| \simeq K(\Bbb Z, 2)$$

---

So I am trying to understand why this means.

Firstly, which category does this take place in? From answer below, I'd like to understand more how $$ \Lambda_\infty \in Fun(BB\Bbb Z, Cat)$$ From the construction given.

> (X') So as in comments
> $$object \in Fun(BB\Bbb Z.Cat) \simeq Map(B\Bbb Z, Fun(C,C)^{\simeq}) \simeq Map( \Bbb Z, \Omega (Fun(C,C)^{\simeq}, id)$$

Where I have omitted the subscript category. It would be helpful elaboration  what adjunction where are using to obtain such equivalence.
As I am still rather unclear why we have these equivalence.

---

2. We construct a new category, $\Lambda_1:= \Lambda_\infty/B\Bbb Z= \Lambda_\infty/A$.

---

Now I don't understand what $(-)/B\Bbb Z$ means. i.e. What kind of colimit are we taking?

> (X) for each $A \in CAlg(Cat)$ some object $BA \in Cat$,
> **$$Mod_{A}(Cat) \simeq Fun(BA, Cat)  $$**

Hence
$$\Lambda_1 \simeq colim _{BA} \Lambda_\infty$$

---

3. We wish to compute $|N\Lambda_1|$. Then as $|\quad|$ is left adjoint.

$$ |\Lambda_1| \simeq colim_A |\Lambda_\infty| \simeq |BA| $$

---

The second equivalence requires the fact that

> (Y) $Spc^{|BA|}   \rightarrow Spc$ is conservative. Does this follow from that $Mod_{|BA|}(Spc) \rightarrow Spc$ is conservative? .

> (Z) An explicit formula for $BA$. It doesn't seem clear to me why we would now have $BB\Bbb Z= K(\Bbb Z,2)$.

Comment: $B(BG)$ only makes sense when $BG$ a topological (or simplicial) group, which only happens when $G$ is abelian, right? Also, what is the "terminal space * with free $G$-action"? Notice that if $EG$ is a contractible space with any $G$ action, then the map $EG\to *$ induces an equivalence $\mbox{hocolim} EG\xrightarrow{\simeq} \mbox{hocolim}*$.

Comment: Hi Gregory, I noticed I have a lot of nonsense there, I edited it - please tell me if anything still does not make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in their context, $C$ has an action of $B\mathbb Z$, not of $\mathbb Z$ ! (Otherwise $C/B\mathbb Z$ wouldn't make sense)
This amounts essentially to a self natural transformation of the identity functor

For the first claim and the commutative square, this is true as geometric realization is a left adjoint $Cat_\infty \to \mathsf{Spaces}$ so if you're taking the homotopy colimit, it is preserved by the left adjoint (and then they explain why their colimit is a homotopy colimit)

For the second claim, in $Fun(BG, \mathsf{Spaces})$,  $*$ is terminal, and the forgetful functor to $\mathsf{Spaces}$ is conservative, in particular any space with $G$-action (note that this is different from what is often called a genuine $G$-space) whose underlying space is contractible is equivalent, in that category, to $*$ with the trivial action, which indeed has homotopy colimit $BG$.

Let me adress your new X,Y,Z concerns.

(X) : no, it's not the case that such a $BA$ exists for any $A$, it's specific to the fact that $A$ here is a group (specifically, $S^1$ or $B\mathbb Z$). In fact, I don't think they're claiming that equivalence, I assume that they're taking the right hand side as a *definition* of a category with $G$-action.

More generally, if you have *any* $\infty$-category $D$, $Fun(BG,D)$ is what we define to be "$D$-objects with $G$-action" (note that $G$ doesn't have to be "in" $D$, whatever that would even mean in such generality). It so happens that in the cases $D= Cat_\infty$ or $\mathsf{Spaces}$, the left hand side also has a meaning, and they happen to agree, but you don't need to know or use that in the proof.

(Y) : For any $\infty$-categories $C,D$, the restriction functor $Fun(C,D)\to Fun(Ob(C),D)$ is conservative, this is just saying that a natural transformation is invertible if and only if each of its components is invertible (which is obvious $1$-categorically, and requires some work $\infty$-categorically, but is not too hard). You then specialize this to $C= BG$ which as only one object, and $D$ whatever. This means that an equivalence between objects with $G$-action is just a $G$-equivariant map which is an equivalence on the underlying objects.

(Z) : $BB\mathbb Z= K(\mathbb Z,2)$ is a classical fact from algebraic topology.

For any (nice) topological group $G$, $\Omega BG\simeq G$, so $\Omega^2BB\mathbb Z \simeq \mathbb Z$, and $BB\mathbb Z$ is simply-connected (essentially by definition of $B(-)$), so it follows that it's a $K(\mathbb Z,2)$.

Comment: I'm still confused. a. For your first paragraph is this not the same as I said in the first point? i.e. $C$ is an object of $Fun(B\Bbb Z, Cat)$ and by $ C/B\Bbb Z$, we apply $colim: Fun(B\Bbb Z, Cat) \rightarrow Cat$  to $C$

b. From your argument of second claim, wouldn't that imply we have $B\Bbb Z$ rather than $BB \Bbb Z$ for the second. equivalence ?

Comment: $C$ is an object of $Fun(BB\mathbb Z,Cat)$, not $Fun(B\mathbb Z, Cat)$ : it's a $B\mathbb Z$-action, not a $\mathbb Z$-action ($G$ actions correspond to objects of $Fun(BG,Cat)$, so if $G=B\mathbb Z$)

Comment: An action of $B\mathbb Z$ on a category $C$ is, morally,  a functor $B\mathbb Z\times C\to C$ which has the same properties as in the usual case but with higher coherences, as is usual in this higher category business. This amounts to a map of ($E_1$-)groups $B\mathbb Z \to Fun(C,C)^\simeq$. But now this is the same as a map of ($E_2$-)groups $\mathbb Z\to Aut(id_C)$ because  the latter is nothing but $\Omega(Fun(C,C),id_C)$; so it is the choice of a natural transformation $id_C\to id_C$ and "some amount of commutativity with itself".

Comment: Of course, the precise meaning of that last sentence is encoded in the symbol "$E_2$" and I'm not sure there's a better way to describe it heuristically, and to get the actual meaning you need to use the actual words, but this is what you get "morally". Of course a natural transformation of $id_C$ will imply that you get a $\mathbb Z$-action on the hom sets, and when everything is as strict as it is in their situation ($C$ is a $1$-category), this somehow completely encodes what is happening, and you automatically get $E_2$, because everything is strictly commutative

Comment: So in their specific situation, the action of $\mathbb Z$ on the hom sets encodes a $B\mathbb Z$-action on $C$, and then you can work with that homotopy-coherently, even though at first everything is strict. And when you do that, you get what I tried to describe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116241/discussion-between-bryan-shih-and-maxime-ramzi).